# Release (Compile) java program without releasing source code

Tags: java, eclipse, compilation, export

I want to release a little program I have been developing for about 11 months now. (Developed entirely in Java).

I am using Eclipse and all I found on this site (and others) is that I have to export "As runnable jar", but this creates a compresed .jar that anyone can extract and see what it is inside.

Any better alternative to this?

Thank you all.

Comment: You may want to obfuscate your code, search for _obfuscator_ and you will find many, including Eclipse plugins .

Comment: Do have in mind that obfuscated code still builds; in certain situations, you can actually work with it (when forced to)

Comment: Thank you, I will search for this asap :)

Comment: I might be missing the point, but you can choose *not* to include the source code in your jar. Or are you actually afraid of someone decompiling your bytecode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can choose *not* to include your source code in the .jar. Using Eclipse Luna this can be done by unchecking the box:

[image]

Comment: So if I **don´t** include the source files, the .jar will still work but won´t include the source code?

Comment: Correct. The important stuff to run the thing is the .class files.